# Узнать состояние клика по кнопке?

Tags: jquery

Есть кнопка. При нажатии на нее один раз, должен открываться div Блок. При нажатии второй раз блок должен закрываться.

Сделал только что бы открывался, а как узнать состояние и потом закрыть?

```
$( ".fa-edit" ).click(function() {
          $( ".cabinet-block-about-me" ).slideDown(300);
        });
```

Comment: `slideToggle()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `slideToggle()` - приводит к плавному сворачиванию (если элемент развернут) или разворачиванию (если элемент свернут) выбранных элементов на странице.

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $("div").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Вуаля!</button>
<br>
<br>
<div>
  <img src="/tags/images/yo.jpg" style="height:150px; float:right; margin:5px 5px">
  <b>Правило.</b> Ё должна использоваться: в случаях возможных разночтений; в словарях; в книгах для изучающих русский язык (т. е. детей и иностранцев); для правильного прочтения редких топонимов, названий или фамилий. Во всех остальных случаях наличие
  буквы ё только затрудняет чтение. Она плохо выглядит, зато хорошо звучит.
</div>
```

Также как второй параметр может передаваться `callback — функция`, заданная в качестве обработчика завершения анимации (появления или скрытия)

**[Подробности...](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B8_%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)**

Answer (score 0):

Используйте [.slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) вместо .slideDown().